# Center text vertically with an image

Tags: html, css

I have this code and the text is properly centered.

**HTML**

```
<div class="holder">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x150/" style="float: left;" />
    <a href="#" class="centered"> some text</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.holder {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    display: table;
}
a {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
img {
    width: 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2P8Yj/1/

How can I make the text aligned to left, next to the image?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add a width to your a:

```
a {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width:200px;
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/2P8Yj/12/)

Comment: Exactly the same thing I wanted to post as an answer:)

Comment: +1 the only answer here which hits at the real problem

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/2P8Yj/18/

I have added the display: table to body the css is as follows

```
      body{display:table}
      .holder { border: 1px solid red; padding: 10px; width: 300px;display: table-row;}
      a {  display: table-cell;
         vertical-align: middle;  }
      img { width: 100px;}
```

Instead of body you can have one more div above it.

Comment: Please mark some answer as the right answer as it will remove the question from the unanswered queue of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Set your anchor to 100% and add some padding if needed:

```
a {  
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    width: 100%; 
    padding-left: 15px; 
   }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2P8Yj/20/

Answer (score 0):

Try this JsFiddle: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2P8Yj/11/)

This are the changes in your CSS, notice the height I have added to the `.holder` and the line-height to your `a`:

```
.holder { 
    border: 1px solid red; 
    padding: 10px; 
    width: 300px;
    height:150px;
    display: block;
}

a {  
    line-height:150px;
    padding-left:20px;
}

img { 
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Did you check your solution thoroughly? http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/2P8Yj/21/ ?

Comment: Ouch, not really. I really thought that it was a short text, then it will work, but indeed if you create a longer text it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You could put `img` and `a` each in a `cell` to create a "proper" table:

HTML:

```
<div class="holder">
    <div class="cell">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x150/" style="float: left;" />
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <a href="#" class="centered"> some text</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.holder {
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    display: table;
}

.cell {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:left;    
}

.cell:nth-child(1) {
    width:105px; /*just to show, better to use padding for second cell*/
}

img {
    width: 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2P8Yj/13/

Comment: Why do you want to create a table if you don't have to?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if changing the `display: table-cell;` to `display: inline-block;` is ok in your situation.

But you can accomplish the same effect with this:

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
img {
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2P8Yj/19/)

Answer (score -1):

You could add `position:relative` and `left:-80px` to your text CSS.

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2P8Yj/3/)

Comment: It is a very dirty way to work with left:-80px if you do not have to. But I did not downvote it ;)

Answer (score -1):

`flaot:left;` might solve your problem.

Comment: There is even a JsFiddle attached. There is no "might" either it does or it does not, the proof is in the Fiddle ;-)